# Simple counting across columns

Tags: stata

In Stata, if you have data such as this:

```
Location    Person 1 Gifts    Person 2 Gifts    Person 3 Gifts     Person 4 Gifts
   1               2                 7                 1                        
   2               4                 1                 12                  2
   3               5                 5                 5                   5
   4               4                                   1
```

What is the easiest way to create a new variable, 'over_three_less_than_six' to count how many people per location gave 3 or more gifts but less than 6. I want it to ignore missing values. So in the above example the new column would output:

```
over_three_less_than_six
          0
          1
          4
          1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beg to differ on style in variable naming! I assume variables such as `gift1` ... `gift4`

```
gen count = 0 

quietly forval j = 1/4 { 
    replace count = count + inrange(gift`j', 3, 5) 
}
```

See also for a detailed review of technique

SJ-9-1  pr0046  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Speaking Stata: Rowwise
        (help rowsort, rowranks if installed) . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q1/09   SJ 9(1):137--157
        shows how to exploit functions, egen functions, and Mata
        for working rowwise; rowsort and rowranks are introduced

.pdf freely available at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0046

```
inlist(gift`j', 3, 4, 5)
```

would also work instead of the `inrange()` call.

Comment: Yes, mine were terrible names. Great response!